# treeview for windows form at right side of the screen

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I want to implement treeview at the right side of the screen right now I have implemented the treeview but it is coming to the left side of the screen. any properties of that for moving it to the right side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at right side of the screen

Does it mean that you want to set the treeview's location to the right side? If so, you can set it via property `Location`.

```
treeView1.Location = new Point(this.Width - treeView1.Width, 0);
```

Or set its `Dock` to `Right`,

```
treeView1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
```

Comment: thanks Kyle. it works like a charm. i have used this one

treeView1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;

Comment: @jeet If this answer helps you, please click √ to mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need always have to stand on the right, you can use `Control.Anchor` Property. Use the Anchor property to define how a control is automatically resized as its parent control is resized. Anchoring a control to its parent control ensures that the anchored edges remain in the same position relative to the edges of the parent control when the parent control is resized.
For example you can use as follow as:

```
Panel pnlMain = new Panel();
// If you want left to right
pnlMain.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);
// If you want only top-right
pnlMain.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);
...
```